# The term 'Get-ObjectAcl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

When i tried run this PS Script :
" Get-ObjectAcl -SamAccountName delegate -ResolveGUIDs | ? {$_.ActiveDirectoryRights -eq "GenericAll"} "

i got error like that:

Get-ObjectAcl : The term 'Get-ObjectAcl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- Get-ObjectAcl -SamAccountName delegate -ResolveGUIDs | ? {$_.ActiveDi ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-ObjectAcl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I searched but i can't find how can i use module Add-ObjectAcl and Get-ObjectAcl

Comment: Do you mean this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-acl?view=powershell-7 or you can also look into this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55415433/powershell-get-acl-with-samaccountname-values

Comment: It would be a good idea to [edit] the question and explain where did you get the idea of calling `Get-ObjectACL` anyway? It is not a MS standard cmdlet. That being said, as you are trying to run a PowerSploit custom cmdlet, [install its module](https://github.com/PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit) first.